# Symfony 4 & Postman access File from post-data POST request

Tags: symfony, file-upload, postman

I'm trying to do an image upload using a Symfony REST API.

However, I'm having problems trying to read the POST request file parameter on Symfony's side using Postman.

On Postman I have the following body on the POST request:

**form-data** POST request with `key=file` and `value=some image`

When the Request reaches Symfony, I have the following:

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{
    $params = $request->request;

    $file = $params->get('image');
    dump($file);

    ...
}
```

The `file` variable is `null`. I have also tried using `$params = $request->files` but the result is the same.

If I dump `$request->getContent()` I can see the file is passing through, but cannot have access to it to do what I need.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure it out, it has something to do with the Postman app I'm using.

Basically, when I choose `form-data` on the body, the Headers tab is not automatically updated to something like `Content-Type` => `multipart/form-data`, it just keeps the previous one it existed (application/json, for example).

When I found this out, I changed the Content-Type to **multipart/form-data** but it was still not working.

It only worked when I unticked the Content-Type on Headers.

Why is that?
I was missing the `boundary` part on the Content-Type, which Postman automatically generates when the body is a form-data and no Content-Type header is generated.

So,

Content-Type = **multipart/form-data** -> doesn't work

Content-Type = **multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary5Qa5cbeHtIOCMAKa** -> works fine (you don't need to specify this, as Postman will make a request with this set)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should use is `$request->files->get('file');`

Comment: nop, nothing comes from $request->files, it's null as I've said above

Comment: I just tried with postman / SF4 and it works correctly, this is weird

Comment: What do you have specified on your headers tab?